# Get information of an a array of links using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I'm trying to get the amount of shares, likes and comments of an array of links .

Is there any method to do that without enter the graph api and ask for each of the links?

I'm using this link to check that:
graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.mydomain.com/link1.php

I would like to do something like this:
graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.mydomain.com/link1.php&id2=http://www.mydomain.com/link2.php&http://www.mydomain.com/link3.php

Answer (score 0):

`http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.example.com/link1.php,http://www.example.com/link2.php`